# CoreClr hosting within different browsers

Tags: silverlight, clr

As I understand, When you run a silverlight application (atleast for case of IE), there is a mini-CLR that build within IE that run as part of the silverlight application.

What happen if I am using some other browser like FireFox, Chrome or Safari. Does these browsers also have CoreCLR embedded within? May be I am just no clear about the architecture as how CoreCLR engine is hosted within different browswers and any info/links will be helpful to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight is run in browsers using a browser plug-in, in much the same way as with Flash.  To quote the [Wikipedia page for Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight):

> The run-time environment for Silverlight is available as a plug-in for most web browsers.

Once you've installed the plug-in, you can use Silverlight in IE, Firefox and Chrome.  The Wikipedia page I linked to above suggests Safari might not support Silverlight, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: Something seems off on that table. Our SL4 application runs fine on Safari and Firefox 3 on my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.